# Counting occurances of a negative number from a list

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to learn LC-3 assembly and am looking at the below example:

```
        .orig   x3100   
        ADD R3, R0, #0  ;copy R0 into R3
        AND R1, R1, #0  ;clear count

        ADD R3, R3, #0  ;test for Neg
        BRZP NEXT       ;count if Neg
        ADD R1, R1, #1

NEXT    AND R2, R2, #0  ;check remaining 15 bits
        ADD R2, R2, #-15
LOOP    ADD R3, R3, R3  ;shift R3 left
        BRZP AGAIN      ;count if Neg
        ADD R1, R1, #1
AGAIN   ADD R2, R2, #1  ;loop until done
        BRN LOOP
```

There's a couple points I don't quite understand:

```
ADD R3, R3, #0 ;test for Neg
```

I don't see how this is testing for a negative value: I'm reading it as it adds nothing to R3, i.e. it does nothing. The following line as well, I don't quite understand what it's doing with `BRZP`.

I want to change this example to instead check from a list of integers:

```
INTEGERS    .fill    84
            .fill    -2
            .fill    -13
            .fill    4
            .fill    -4
```

In the above, there's three negative integers, so the count (R1) would then be 3 at program end. How would I do this?

Comment: That example seems to count set bits in a single number, not detect negative numbers in an array. So it isn't very useful. Anyway, adding zero is used to set the flags so you can check whether the number is negative. The `BRZP` is used to skip the increment if it's zero or positive, that is not negative. It is used here to check the most significant bit (the sign bit) while shifting all the other bits into that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `ADD R3, R3, #0 ;test for Neg` sets flags based on the result, so the conditional branch will be based on the result that `ADD` stores into `R3`.

As Jester points out, it seems to be looping on counting set bits in a single integer, using `add r3,r3,r3` to left-shift it and set flags.

---

I don't know lc3 specifically, but it looks like you could save an instruction by clearing the counter and having the `ADD R3, R0, #0  ;copy R0 into R3` take care of setting flags initially.

LC3 doesn't have `mov` instructions, I take it.  You copy data around by adding an immediate zero, since unlike x86, it uses 3-operand instructions where the dest doesn't have to be one of the src instructions.